# How get a variable from HTML in JavaScript/Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using Zend Framework 2. 
I would like to know how to get data defined in html in my javascript code.

html

```
<tr class="MyClass" data-MyData="<?php echo json_encode($array);?>">
```

javascript

```
$(document).on('click','.MyClass', function () {

        var temp =document.getElementsByClassName("data-MyData");

        $.ajax({
            url: path_server + "pathDefinedInMyConfig",
            type: 'post',
            encode: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'temp ': temp 
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //some code
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("ERROR");
            }
        });
});
```

The problem is I don't have access to row in my Controller method. And i want to have access to My $array defined in html in my Controller.

Comment: do you know which element is the `tr` with class `MyClass` in your page? I mean: 1st? 3rd? 4th?

Comment: you may change `var temp =document.getElementsByClassName("data-MyData");` to `var tmp = this.getAttribute('data-MyData');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are trying to find a `class` by the name `data-MyData`, but the object you "want" to look for is "MyClass"

Try something like `var temp =document.getElementsByClassName("MyClass").attr("data-MyData");`

Even better is that since you click on the object with `MyClass` you can use `$(this).attr('data-MyData');`

then result will look like: `var temp = $(this).attr('data-MyData');`

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `temp` var assignment line:

```
var temp =document.getElementsByClassName("data-MyData");
```

with this one:

```
var temp = this.getAttribute("data-MyData");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use jQuery use the following:

```
$('.MyClass').data('MyData')
```

or

```
 $('.MyClass').attr('data-MyData')
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this-

```
$(document).on('click','.MyClass', function () {

        var temp =$(this).attr('data-MyData');

        $.ajax({
            url: path_server + "pathDefinedInMyConfig",
            type: 'post',
            encode: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'temp ': temp 
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //some code
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("ERROR");
            }
        });});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong selector. `document.getElementsByClassNames()` returns the collections so you have to loop through to get the target element:

```
var temp =document.getElementsByClassName('MyClass');
[].forEach.call(temp, function(el){
   console.log(el.dataset['MyData']);
});
```

or as you are using jQuery then you can use `.data()`:

```
var temp =$(this).data("MyData");
```

and with javascript:

```
var temp =this.dataset["MyData"];
// var temp =this.dataset.MyData; // <---this way too.
```